# Where can I get PIC18F4455.lib file to build a code..?

Tags: microchip

I want to compile and debug the code for PIC18F4455 device.
.lib file is missing in this project code.

Where can I get this PIC18F4455.lib file..? I have searched it in the 
'C:Program/Microchip' folder.. But could'nt find it there..

Can anybody help with this..??

Regards,
Dhara

Comment: Why do you think you need a lib file? You probably just need a .h file ...

Comment: Actually I am working on the code which was written by other person and in that project file- P18F4455.lib, P18F4455.h and 18F4455.lkr are missing. I need to compile and debug this code. I added the 18F4455_g.lkr (generic linker for 18F PIC devices) but the other 2 (.lib and .h) are still missing..

Comment: Those files are usually automatically linked by the Microchip compiler and only an #include <xc.h> is required to get all the device related library.

Answer (score 0):

Add the definition below to tell the compiler to include the file.

```
 #include <xc.h>
```

If you are using any other compiler than the Microchip XC compiler, it's suggested you download the latest IDE and latest official compiler.